# Visual Studio Online Permission Management

Tags: user-permissions, azure-devops

We have recently moved to Visual Studio Online. In there we have multiple projects. There are many people in different roles in our team.

The last thing that challenged me was about access right for certain things in VSO.

Here is the scenario for Employee "E1".

1. "E1" should be able to contribute to project "P1". It should be able to see the changesets and make changes in the code. And it should also be able to see/modify/delete all WorkItems in "P1" project.
2. "E1" should be able to see project "P2" 's changesets, workitems but E1 should not be able to modify workitems or source code in "P2"
3. "E1" should be able to access to "P3" but only for WorkItems with read-only access.
4. "E1" should be able to access to "P4" to manage WorkItems with read-write access. It should not see Changeset.

Can I setup E1 access to P1, P2, P3, P4 projects based on the given restriction ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VSO provide several groups with different access permission to the project. You can add your users to corresponding groups to control their permission or set the permission for user directly.

To set the permission to work items:

1. Open your project from web portal
2. Click “Manage Project” icon in the up right corner.
3. Click “Area” tab.
4. Right click on the area and select “Security”.

Then you can edit the permission for these groups and users. To control the access to work items, you can set the permission for “Edit work items in this node” and “View work items in this node”.

[image]

One thing you need to know is that the work items cannot be deleted from web portal. You can only delete the work item from command line via “witadmin destroywi” command and you must be a member of the “Team Foundation Administrators” security group or the “Project Administrators” security group for the team project collection. Instruction about destroywi: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx

To set the permission to code resource:

1.Open your project from web portal.

2.Click “Code” tab.

3.Right click your code resource and select “Security…”

Set “Read” permission to read the code/changeset and set “Check In” permission to make changes in the code.

[image]

For more information about VSO permission, please refer to this link from MSDN for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @eddie. Looks like there were many security configurations that I was not aware in VSO.